# addEventListener is not working when it contains append?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, appendchild

The website have a button called (svgAdd) where everytime I click this button it's supposed to add a point to the listBody div. but it is not working I tried a lot of ways but nothing worked, and if your thinking about using += point then it will remove the value of the textarea everytime I add a point to the listbody.

```
let count = 0;
$(`#svgNew`).click(function() {
      
    let point = 
        `
        <div class="point d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" id="point">
            <div class="pointTxt" id="pointTxt">
                <p class="list-font">Enter Your Text</p>
                <textarea id="txtA" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="pointIcon${count}" id="pointIcon">
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
    let list =
        `
        <div class="list col-lg-4" id="list${count}">
        <div class="listHead d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <div class="listHeadSet" id="listHeadSet${count}">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="list-svg" id="svgAdd${count}" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-plus"><line x1="12" y1="5" x2="12" y2="19"></line><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line></svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="list-svg" id="svgDelete${count}" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path></svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="list-svg" id="svgRemove${count}" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-file-minus"><path d="M14 2H6a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v16a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V8z"></path><polyline points="14 2 14 8 20 8"></polyline><line x1="9" y1="15" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="listHeadTitle" id="listHeadTitle${count}">
            <h1 class="titleH list-font" id="titleH${count}">Title</h1>
            <input type="text" class="list-font titleInp" id="titleInp${count}" aria-label="Default" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Title">
        </div>
        <div class="listHeadIcons">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="list-svg" id="svgEdit${count}" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-2"><path d="M17 3a2.828 2.828 0 1 1 4 4L7.5 20.5 2 22l1.5-5.5L17 3z"></path></svg>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="list-svg" id="svgSet${count}" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-sliders"><line x1="4" y1="21" x2="4" y2="14"></line><line x1="4" y1="10" x2="4" y2="3"></line><line x1="12" y1="21" x2="12" y2="12"></line><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="3"></line><line x1="20" y1="21" x2="20" y2="16"></line><line x1="20" y1="12" x2="20" y2="3"></line><line x1="1" y1="14" x2="7" y2="14"></line><line x1="9" y1="8" x2="15" y2="8"></line><line x1="17" y1="16" x2="23" y2="16"></line></svg>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="listBody${count}" id="listBody${count}"></div>
        </div>
        `;

       $(`.lists`).append(list);

       const listx = document.querySelector(`#list${count}`);
       const svgAdd = document.querySelector(`#svgAdd${count}`);
       const svgDelete = document.querySelector(`#svgDelete${count}`);
       const svgRemove = document.querySelector(`#svgRemove${count}`);
       const listHeadTitle = document.querySelector(`#listHeadTitle${count}`);
       const titleH = document.querySelector(`#titleH${count}`);
       const titleInp = document.querySelector(`#titleInp${count}`);
       const svgEdit = document.querySelector(`#svgEdit${count}`);
       const svgSet = document.querySelector(`#svgSet${count}`);
       const listHeadSet = document.querySelector(`#listHeadSet${count}`);
       const listBody = document.querySelector(`#listBody${count}`);

       let titleArr = [];
       let text = "";
       svgEdit.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
          titleH.classList.toggle(`hidden`);
          titleInp.classList.toggle(`show`);
          let inpValue = titleInp.value;
          if (inpValue.length == 0) titleH.innerHTML = titleArr[titleArr.length];
          else if (inpValue.length <= 15) titleH.innerHTML = inpValue; titleArr.push(titleInp.value);
       });
       svgSet.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
           listHeadTitle.classList.toggle(`hidden`);
           svgEdit.classList.toggle(`hidden`);
           listHeadSet.classList.toggle(`show`);
       });
       svgRemove.addEventListener("click", ()=> {listx.remove()});
       svgAdd.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
            $(`#listBody${count}`).append(point);
       })
       count++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not completely use Jquery for your element selection also. With that you do not need to use "addEventListener"

```
   const listx = $(`#list${count}`);
   const svgAdd = $(`#svgAdd${count}`);
   const svgDelete = $(`#svgDelete${count}`);
   const svgRemove = $(`#svgRemove${count}`);
   const listHeadTitle = $(`#listHeadTitle${count}`);
   const titleH = $(`#titleH${count}`);
   const titleInp = $(`#titleInp${count}`);
   const svgEdit = $(`#svgEdit${count}`);
   const svgSet = $(`#svgSet${count}`);
   const listHeadSet = $(`#listHeadSet${count}`);
   const listBody = $(`#listBody${count}`);
   
   let titleArr = [];
   let text = "";
   svgEdit.on("click", ()=> {
      titleH.toggleClass(`hidden`);
      titleInp.toggleClass(`show`);
      let inpValue = titleInp.value;
      if (inpValue.length == 0) titleH.innerHTML = titleArr[titleArr.length];
      else if (inpValue.length <= 15) titleH.innerHTML = inpValue; 
      titleArr.push(titleInp.value);
   });
   svgSet.on("click", ()=> {
       listHeadTitle.toggleClass(`hidden`);
       svgEdit.toggleClass(`hidden`);
       listHeadSet.toggleClass(`show`);
   });
   svgRemove.on("click", ()=> {listx.remove()});
   svgAdd.on("click", ()=> {
        $(`#listBody${count}`).append(point);
   })
   count++;
```

Comment: It didn't work, the console says "cannot read property toggle of undefined "!!!

Comment: use ".toggleClass(`className`)" instead of "classList.toggle()"

Comment: the append child for the listBody is still not working